# Google Tag Manager and AB Testing for mobile

Tags: google-tag-manager, ab-testing

I defined a new ab testing experiment using google tag manager for my android
But seems whatever I am trying to do I always get the default value.
I couldn't find to much documentation about google ab-testing for mobile.
Does anyone know how to define it properly?

Comment: Maybe you can share a snippet around your integration so that we can review it and make sure we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A/B tests will always show you the same test on the same device. This is needed to produce accurate test results. Otherwise, you can't be certain the user was swayed by the variant or that the user was simply ready to respond.

Comment: Do you mean that I used some test mode? I tried to use 5 different phones and all of them got the same values. I also tried to uninstall and reinstall the app nothing changed.